# Sql Server: Isolating particular character

Tags: sql-server, character

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2.  There are a number of records that have this funky � character in a particular column.  I'd like to isolate just those records and do a Replace() on them.  The problem I'm having is when I run this query:

```
select * from stories where body like '%�%' and publishdate = 20110131
```

It will return stories where the � isn't in the body column.  In each of those cases that I've checked, there is a normal ? character in the contents of the body column.  So it seems that like '%�%' is matching both ? and �.  Is there any Cast or Convert magic I can do to return records that actually have the � character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `N` prefix and a binary `COLLATE` clause do the job?

```
CREATE TABLE #stories
(
body nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #stories
SELECT N'normal ? char' UNION ALL SELECT N'funky � char' 

SELECT *
FROM #stories
WHERE body like '%�%'

SELECT *
FROM #stories
WHERE body like N'%�%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2

DROP TABLE #stories
```

Comment: Perfect.  And it looks like this update statement will do the job:  update #stories set body = Replace(body, N'�'COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, ' ') WHERE body like N'%�%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2